# creating a floating div and two static divs inside parent

Tags: html, css

i know there are hundred topics opened on the float div topic but i couldn't find answer for my problem there, for some reason nothing worked for me.
i have a parent div on which i want to put two static divs one to the right and one to the left and another one div containing the main information floating between them, i.e, in equal distance between them. but for some reason it wont work for me. every change i make it kicks the right div down or stick the main div to the right\left. here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "tryout.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="super_wrap">
    <div class="ADDVERTISEMENT"><img src="add.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="wrap">
    some data
    </div>
    <div class="ADDVERTISEMENT2"><img src="add.jpg" /></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```css
.ADDVERTISEMENT{
margin-top:10px;
float:left;
margin-left:0 auto;
margin-right:0 auto;
}
.ADDVERTISEMENT2{
margin-top:10px;
float:right;
margin-left:0 auto;
margin-right:0 auto;
}
#wrap {
display: inline-block;
width:960px;
padding:10px;
background:red;
margin-left:0 auto;
margin-right:0 auto;
}
#super_wrap{
width:100%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
text-align:center
```

on `#super_wrap`, and move `#wrap` to be third, after `#ADDVERTISEMENT2`. Then `#wrap` element should center.

Note: you will still have `#wrap` dropping to the next line if there is not enough room for all 3 within `#super_wrap`

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qN4Tp/

Comment: hi, it worked on chrome but didnt work on explorer. any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: It works in ie 9 & 10 (see the jsfiddle), so if you're having a problem in one of those versions, double-check your code. There's nothing unusual about these declarations, so I doubt there's an IE8 or IE7- specific issue (I can't tell because jsfiddle doesn't support IE below 9). If it's IE6, then you'd have a problem because you cannot set divs to inline-blocks in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few wrong css declarations, which will cause you issues:

```
margin-left:0 auto;
margin-right:0 auto;
```

Applying shorthand only works for `margin:` but not for `margin-right:`

Either do `margin:0 auto;` or

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

If you want the middle div to display in the middle, you can try ordering your html like this:

Ad1
Ad2
Wrap

See demo:
http://jsbin.com/oqujet/1/edit

Comment: hi, the problem with your solution is that it streches only because the with of the middle div is 100%, if you change it to 960 putin disapears. the thing with the margin i will take into consideration. thanks you.

Comment: you can set the width on the parent

Comment: true, but it will be static, i was looking for a dynamic solution.